# App restart when revoke from background after some time?

Tags: android, wiki, activity-lifecycle, background-service, android-background

In my android Application,**I have an issue in which if I open app from background after some time (30 or 40 min)** , that time my app got restart can any one have suggestion on it.

I have gone through almost question before asking this one,but can't find any suggestion or help.

Thanks in advance, any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: This is perfectly normal. [Your process will not live forever](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html). Beyond that, Stack Overflow is for programming questions -- what is your question?

Comment: Hello,@CommonsWare my question is why its restart in just 30 - 40 mins ?why not for long time. can you please explain this.

Comment: This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html). Your process can be terminated **at any time** once it moves into the background, to free up system RAM for other apps and their processes, as Android devices do not have infinite amounts of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.